# Why is 大消费组 used here?

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context, expressions

我分管该公司研究部大消费组6个消费类行业。
I'm in charge of 6 consumer industries of the research department in this company. I don't understand 大消费组.  It seems to be redundant.

Why is 大消费组 used here? What does it mean in this sentence?

Comment: Very bad English and/or translation. Put some more context. The sentence before and the sentence after for instance. 
"I am in charge of 6 consumer industries of the Big Consumption Team in the research department of this company." is not acceptable.

Comment: 大消费 seems to be referring to 高消費者, i.e., premium customers.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you should omit it. It's something like **Big Consumption Team/Division** in the research department. It denotes the Team "I" **work in**, whereas `消费类行业` denotes the target industries "I" **work on/am in charge of**.

Thus, the sentence should be,

> I am in charge of 6 consumer industries of the Big Consumption Team in the research department of this company.